# how to define a two dimensional const array of strings in objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I have declared the following constant which works:

```
NSString * const LETTER_SELECTED[] = {@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F"};
```

and now I want to declare a similar constant but with dimension two which does not work:

```
NSString * const LETTER_SELECTED[][] = {
                        {@"A",@"uc"},
                        {@"b",@"lc"},
                        {@"c",@"lc"},
                        {@"d",@"lc"},
                        {@"E",@"uc"},
                        {@"f",@"lc"}};
```

I am a C programmer, any idea how to declare this in Objective-C ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is what an `NSArray` looks like in objective-c.

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *my2DArrayOfStrings;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.my2DArrayOfStrings = @[
                                @[ @"A", @"uc" ],
                                @[ @"b", @"lc" ],
                                @[ @"c", @"lc" ],
                                @[ @"d", @"lc" ],
                                ];
    return self;
}
@end
```

However, in your example it *seems* like what you *really* want is an `NSDictionary`.

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *stringDictionary;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.stringDictionary = @{
                              @"A" : @"uc",
                              @"b" : @"lc",
                              @"c" : @"lc",
                              @"d" : @"lc",
                              };
    return self;
}
@end
```